# Counting the number of orbits finite groups of "diagonal type"

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $n$, $k$, $r_1, \dots, r_k$ be positive integers.
For each $i \in [k]:=\{1,\dots,k\}$, suppose we are given $n$ permutations of the the set $[r_i]$, that is $f_1^{(i)}, \dots, f_n^{(i)}$ in $\mathfrak{S}_{r_i}$.
Suppose that the group generated by these $n$ permutations acts transitively on  $[r_i]$, i.e., it has a single orbit.

Now, for each $j \in [n]$, let $g_j := (f_j^{(1)}, \dots , f_j^{(k)}) \in \mathfrak{S}_{r_1} \times \dots \times \mathfrak{S}_{r_k}$, which acts on the finite ``box product'' set $B := [r_1] \times \dots \times [r_k]$ in the obvious way. Now consider the group $G$ of permutations of $B$ generated by $g_1, \dots, g_n$.

> **Question 1:** Given the data $n$, $k$, $r_1, \dots, r_k$ and no information on the permutations $f_j^{(i)}$ (except the transitivity hypotheses above), what is the largest number of distinct orbits that the group $G$ may have?

The case $n=1$ is easy because then each $f_1^{(i)}$ must be a cyclic permutation of order $\mathrm{lcm}(r_1,\dots, r_k)$ and so there are 
$$
\frac{r_1 \dots r_k}{\mathrm{lcm}(r_1,\dots, r_k)} \tag{1}
$$
distinct orbits.

For arbitrary $n$, note that 
$$
\frac{r_1 \dots r_k}{\max(r_1,\dots, r_k)} \tag{2}
$$
is always an upper bound for the number of orbits, since each orbit projects in each $i$-th coordinate to the whole $[r_i]$.

Here is an example with $n=k=2$, $r_1=2$, $r_2=3$ where $f_1^{(1)} = \mathrm{id}$ and all the other permutations have order $2$. Then there is a single orbit:
[image]

This example shows that the upper bound (2) is not sharp. Incidentally, the bound (1) obtained for $n=1$ holds in this case. It's hard to imagine how more permutations (i.e., bigger $n$) could produce less orbits, so I ask:

> **Question 2:** For $n \geq 2$, is the quantity (1) an upper bound for the number of orbits?

Comment: Let $G^{(i)}$ be the subgroup of $S_{r_i}$ generated by the permutations $g^{(i)}_j$ for $j = 1,\ldots,n$. By the orbit-counting lemma, the number of orbits of $G$ is at most $|G^{(1)}| \ldots |G^{(k)}| / |G|$. This generalizes your upper bound for the $1$-generator case. (Two typos: $g_j$ has $k$ components, not $n$; I think $f_j^{(1)}$ should be $g_j$ below the question.)

Comment: @MarkWildon corrected the typos, thanks.